# C++ Pugixml get children of parent by attribute id

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, pugixml

For example:

```
<levels>
    <level id="1">
        <somestuff></somestuff>
    </level>
    <level id="2">
        <somestuff></somestuff>
    </level>
</levels>
```

How do you get the data of level with id 1?
Now i am using `pugi::xml_node level = levels.child("level")` But that return all levels..

Regards,
GJJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
levels.find_child_by_attribute("level", "id", "1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
for (pugi::xml_node ambil = doc.child("levels").child("level"); ambil; ambil = ambil.next_sibling("level"))
{
    int id = ambil.attribute("id").as_int();
    CCLog("%d",id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

foreach children & compare attribute value.
e.g.

```
for (const auto& node : levels.children("level"))
{
    if (node.attribute("id").as_int() == 1)
    {
        // TODO: add ur code here
    }
}
```